# Is there a limit to the query plan size in dm_exec_text_query_plan? My plan is getting cut off

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using ssms 2012 to query a 2008R2 instance, I am trying to get a plan for a specific query using the DMVs like this:

```
SELECT t.text
    , p.query_plan
from sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
cross join sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) t
cross join sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan(qs.plan_handle,0,-1) p
where t.text like ...
```

The query plan column is getting cut off after 43,679 characters.  Ending with

```
   < /Outp
```

instead of

```
< /ShowPlanXML>
```

I tested this with a smaller query and the whole text was returned.  The query in question is not that complex, but has a lot of columns, which may be making it a bit more verbose.  Also, the value returned is not a link to the plan but just the XML in text form.
Is there a limit to what is stored in plan cache or I am doing something wrong in SSMS that it is not returning the value as a plan link in the column?

Comment: Where are you outputting this? Management Studio? What operating system, Vista? Yep, known issue: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/344150/ssms-grid-will-not-display-43-679-characters-from-varchar-max http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/344117/ssms-grid-will-not-display-10-919-characters-from-varbinary-max - it says fixed, so not sure why you are still seeing this.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for the related connects.  Maybe this is something specific to the DMV, as the other one handles it correctly.  The data is supposed to be returned as NVARCHAR(MAX), not varbinary.  Do you think it deserves another connect?

Comment: Well comment on those two for sure. My item was about strings, not varbinary, and I'm sure they didn't intend for the "fix" to be to return some arbitrary portion of the string. I have no idea of the significance of 43,679 characters, but it clearly must be related.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Interesting, looks like Steve Kass has a connect out there for this already: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/259268  Open since 2007 :O

Comment: yeah, don't hold your breath. I didn't find that one in my search because I wasn't looking for issues with this DMV in particular... even if they fixed the DMV to have the right output type, there's still some fundamental problem here with text getting prematurely truncated at 43,679 bytes. Absolutely no idea what is significant about that number but it is a real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the bug Aaron mentions in comments is in play here, you should be able to get around it with an SSMS tweak.  You can directly cast the result of your query into the xml data type, and then return it that way.

If you're returning the XML in a grid view, go to Tools/Options/Query Results/SQL Server/Results to Grid and see what the setting for Maximum Characters Retrieved for XML data is, and bump it up to "Unlimited".  This should allow you to circumvent the varchar limit.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops!  Wrong DMV.  I needed to use dm_exec_query_plan not dm_exec_text_query_plan.  That solved it - thanks for the replies.

Comment: It should still not truncate at 43,679, so there is still a problem even if you're looking at the text version of the plan rather than the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Posting another answer as this may help someone else out in the future.  There are a few approaches that I've found to work around the 43,679 character limitation in outputs displayed in Grid View as specific to this question.  These approaches also work if your plan exceeds the SQL XML Data Type limit of 128 nested nodes.

The first, and arguably easiest option, is to fire up PowerShell ISE and follow the instructions outlined on [this blog post by Patrick Keisler](http://www.patrickkeisler.com/2013/09/the-case-of-null-queryplan.html). Paste his script into the ISE editor, adjust the OFFSET values (recommended), output paths/names, and then run everything to generate the final sqlplan file.

If you don't want to use PowerShell, a *kludgy* TSQL method I cobbled together can also be used, as follows:

```
-- Quick and dirty script to output large execution plans from cache
--  Be sure to replace Plan Handle and Offset Values Below
DECLARE @query_plan_nvarmax NVARCHAR(MAX), @len_out INT, @sub_str INT = 0, @sub_end INT = 43679
DECLARE @full_query_plan TABLE
    (
        line INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        qp_line NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )

SELECT @query_plan_nvarmax = query_plan,
       @len_out = LEN(query_plan)--, CAST(query_plan AS XML) as xml_query_plan
--   Usage:  Get Query Offset Values From sys.dm_exec_query_stats DMV
--   sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan(plan_handle, OFFSET_START|DEFAULT, OFFSET_END|DEFAULT)
FROM sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan(0x050005005EDA4857307D56540300000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 10078, 83616)


WHILE @sub_str < @len_out
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @full_query_plan (qp_line)
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@query_plan_nvarmax, @sub_str, @sub_end)

    SET @sub_str = @sub_end
    SET @sub_end = @sub_end + 43679
    IF @sub_end > @len_out
        SET @sub_end = @len_out
END

-- Save Output of qp_line column to text editor and remove newline characters \r\n
--  I prefer Notepad++, but any editor will suffice then save output as a .sqlplan and open in SSMS
SELECT *
FROM @full_query_plan
```

Take note, you'll need to edit the output of the query in an external text editor to remove the newline characters `\r\n` and save the result as a `.sqlplan` file.